# Keyboard shortcuts for screenshot on Ubuntu 20.04 running on a MacBook Pro

Tags: shortcut-keys, macbook-pro, screenshot

For frequent sharpshooters, like me, a short-cut on Mac Key boards is difficult.
There is a method of launching the "screenshot" app, for which we need to go to applications every time.
As is the case with windows keyboards, PrntSrcn and other combination are quite handy to clip a part of a given window, a window itself or the whole screen.
Do we have such thing for mac keyboards as well?

**Applications → Settings → Keyboard shortcuts** - Doesn't allow to reset the other shortcuts, where it appears everywhere the combination of <kbd>Print</kbd> key.

Comment: In Ubuntu you can use `Print Screen` key to take screenshots.

Comment: @5hifaT
Sure! 
Doing the very same on my Windows machines...   But, MBP don't have that... This was the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

macbook pro does not have a `print screen` button due to touch bar, which is the default button in case of PC.

The default button for screenshot can be checked in settings. Press `super key` (`windows` button on PC or `command` button on mac), and type `shortcut` and select keyboard shortcuts.

Start typing `screenshot` and shortcuts related to screenshots will appear in front of you.

If you want to enable custom shortcuts, then erase the `screenshot` typed earlier and scroll down to bottom and click the `plus` sign at the very bottom. For the name field enter `screenshot full` (or whatever you wish to name it) and in the command section type `gnome-screenshot` and click on the `set shortcut` and press the key combination you want to take screenshot of the whole screen.

If you want to take screenshot of an area which you want to select (a crosshair will appear and then you have to press and drag to select an area and screenshot will be taken of this area only), then instead of just `gnome-screenshot` type `gnome-screenshot -a` and then select the key combination you want.

If you use `gnome-screenshot -w` in the `command` field then it will take the screenshot of the current windows which is highlighted.

All these screenshot will be saved to the `Pictures` folder in the home directory.

Just as we used `-a` and `-w` at the end of `gnome-screenshot` command, there are several others called as flags. Open terminal and type `gnome-screenshot -h` and this will display all the available flags.

Comment: That "scroll down to bottom and click the plus sign at the very bottom. For the name field enter screenshot full" worked nicely.  
For some reasons, I was not able to change it from Applications → Settings → Keyboard shortcuts.  

gnome-screenshot -c (sending the grab directly to clipboard) is going to be the most useful for me.  

Thanks from the person with reputation less than 15!
:)

Comment: @V3S Consider accepting my answer and upvote it, if this solution helped you.

Comment: I upvoted it already (but being a person with reputation 13, it won't count my vote!).  
I forgot to accept the answer.  
It surely helped me and is going to save a lot of my time..

Thanks :)